# Roller Blind in window ingress

Tags: wood, adhesive, blinds

I am attaching a roller blind in a window ingress and the lintel is steel which is proving hard to get through. Will it hold if I attach a batten of wood in the ingress with grab adhesive to the plaster and attach the blind to the wood? What adhesive would you recommend?

Comment: It depends on how you're planning on attaching the batten.

Comment: @SiHa Sorry, it appears it removed the rest of my sentence! I was planning to use grab adhesive. I updated my question.

Comment: What is "grab adhesive"? I wouldn't think there should be much of a load on blinds, but if someone pulls too hard, anything glued to plaster could come off  - either pulling the glue off the plaster itself, or more likely, pulling the plaster off whatever it's attached to.

Comment: @FreeMan https://www.screwfix.com/c/sealants-adhesives/grab-adhesives/cat850076

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you could secure it to the drywall any excess downward force will pull the blind off as the surface of the drywall will separate.
The options are to either drill into the lintel with a suitable metal bit or attach the blind to the vertical part of the window jamb with mounting brackets.